# Configuring Sharepoint 2010 to send emails using C sharp with aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, configuration, sharepoint-2010

I want to configure sharepoint 2010 to send mails using c sharp coding. I googled with many articles. None of it worked fine.

Can any one help me to ** configure the mail settings in sharepoint 2010 central administration ** and send mails using c# coding?

Comment: What tutorials did you try and what errors did you get?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the following page including sample c# code:

- [How to send an e-mail with attachment from SharePoint](http://edwin.vriethoff.net/2007/10/02/how-to-send-an-e-mail-with-attachment-from-sharepoint/)

The shortest way is to use SPUtility like so:

```
SPUtility.SendEmail(SPContext.Current.Web, false, false,
                    "test@example.com", "E-mail title", "E-mail body");
```

To configure Mail settings in Central Administration you only have to go to your Central Administration > System Settings > Outgoing E-Mail Settings. There you can set your Outbound SMTP server, from and reply-to address and you are good to go. The hard thing is probably to set up your SMTP server, but this should already be done when you are using MS Exchange.

Comment: If you're using Exchange, don't forget to configure it to accept emails from your SharePoint machine.